# Winforms+Oracle одновременная работа приложений 32 и 64 bit

Tags: winforms, oracle

Есть приложения, написанные на delphi и .Net. Все работают с БД Oracle, все пока что 32bit

Естественно, хочется перевести хотя бы .net на 64bit (внести изменения в дельфийское ПО возможности нет)

Представляется, что нужно на машинах клиента поставить два клиента Oracle - 32 и 64 bit.

Возможна ли одновременная работа 32 и 64 клиентов Oracle?
В интернетах пишут что нужно переключать переменные окружения для oracle, но это не реально, т.к. одновременно могут быть запущены как дельфийские 32 так и net'овские 64bit приложения

Comment: Каждое приложение само может менять свои переменные окружения, не обязательно брать все от ОС

Comment: Рассмотрите возможность перехода на [`Oracle.ManagedDataAccess`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/) — это драйвер БД, не зависящий от клиента Oracle. С ним .Net приложения вообще никому не будут мешать.

Comment: @defaultlocale к сожалению, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess не поддерживает UDTs типы, обильно используемые в ПО на .Net

Comment: @Mike интересное предложение. Был опыт применения этого метода вкупе с oracle client?

Comment: Конкретно с битностью не игрался. но у меня на машине одной были клиенты двух версий. И перловые скрипты перед тем как отрыть соединение с БД выставляли нужное окружение. Но вам надо еще сделать что бы приложение нужные dll подхватило. в nix бы это разруливалось то же окружением, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, на винде не знаю, чем она пользуется. И кстати, в крайнем случае приложение можно запускать .bat-ником который перед запуском установит нужное окружение

Comment: @Mike спасибо, буду пробовать, оформите как ответ